# Delphi Send POST with TIdHttp and special characters

Tags: delphi, idhttp

I do a post for authentication using TIdHttp normally, but when the username has a special character it does not work, analyzing the POST by the browser I see the conversion, for example the username "aforça" in the browser stays "afor%E7a", even sending me what the browser sends, ie "afor% E7a" also does not work.

I've tried the following:

```
var
 Params2: TStringList;
begin
    Params2 := TStringList.Create;
    Params2.Add('username=' + UTF8String('aforça'));
    Params2.Add('password=' + UTF8String('123456'));
    xHtmlRetorno := IdHttp.Post('urlsite.com', Params2);
end;
```

does not work.

searching how to do, I found the following:

```
var
 Params3 : TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  Params3 := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  Params3.AddFormField('username', UTF8Encode('aforça'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
  Params3.AddFormField('password', UTF8Encode('123456'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
  xHtmlRetorno := IdHttp.Post('urlsite.com', Params3);
end;
```

which also did not work ...

Even though I send as the browser sends, it does not work.

```
var
 Params2: TStringList;
begin
    Params2 := TStringList.Create;
    Params2.Add('username=' + UTF8String('afor%E7a'));
    Params2.Add('password=' + UTF8String('123456'));
    xHtmlRetorno := IdHttp.Post('urlsite.com', Params2);
end;
```

how can I do this, since I can only authenticate with user that can not special characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of Delphi and Indy are you using? Modern versions of Delphi use Unicode strings and that is what Indy expects (so don't call `UTF8Encode()` manually like you are), and `TIdHTTP.Post()` encodes a posted `TStrings` object to UTF-8 by default. The UTF-8 encoded form of `aforça` is `afor%C3%A7a`, not `afor%E7a`. If you need the latter, you have to use `Post()`'s optional `AByteEncoding` parameter to specify a different charset encoding, such as `IndyTextEncoding(1252)`/`CharsetToEncoding('Windows-1252')` or `IndyTextEncoding(28591)`/`CharsetToEncoding('ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: I use delphi 10.1 berlin, and the standard version of the indy that comes with it. how would the correct way with this version be?

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you !!